# merge pandas MultiIndex is very slow

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I notice that pandas is very slow on merge DataFrames based on MultiIndex. Assign value is also sometimes slow

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime
import string
import random

start = datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

columns = [id_generator() for i in range(1000)]
dateindex = pd.date_range(start, end)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (len(dateindex), len(columns))), columns=columns, index=dateindex)
df.columns = df.columns.rename('Name')
df.index = df.index.rename('Date')

df1 = df.pct_change(1).stack().rename('change1').to_frame()
df2 = df.pct_change(2).stack().rename('change2').to_frame()

df3 = df1.reset_index()
df4 = df2.reset_index()



%timeit pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
In [11]: 46.7 s ± 656 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pd.merge(df3, df4, on=['Date', 'Name'])
In [12]: 3.17 s ± 168 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The speed is more than 10 times slower. Anyone know what is going on? Is it always better to rest index and join on columns instead of MultiIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Let use `join`:

```
%timeit df1.join(df2)

1 loop, best of 3: 647 ms per loop
```

Comment: I am reading some document: pd.join is actually using pd.merge. Why it is causing a performance difference?